# First time animating is glitchy

Tags: ios, swift

I am animating a view `gradientView` in/out using the following:

```
func hideOrShowGradientView(hide: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.gradientView.isHidden = hide
    })
}
```

This works well, but on the first time, there is no animation.  It just appears.  On the second and third time it works wonderfully.  I've tried calling the animate block on the main thread but no luck there.  Why is this animation failing to occur on the first and only first time around?  Should I be using another animation method?

Comment: Where are you calling this? If the first one was in `viewDidLoad`, for example, that’s too early in the process. (In answer to your main thread comment, all UI updates always have to happen on the main thread.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had too much going on the main thread in the init method, which was being called only on the first time the view was being presented.  Moved unnecessary initialization into view did appear

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`. It forces the view and it's subviews to complete any of it's pending animations immediately, which might be interfering with your animation. You can use it like this:

```
func hideOrShowGradientView(hide: Bool) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.gradientView.isHidden = hide
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Apple recommends calling `layoutIfNeeded()` twice, once before the animation block which forces a redraw on the view and it's subviews, and it completes any pending animations on the view without waiting for the next update cycle, and call it the second time inside the animation block to make sure that the animation changes will be applied immediately.